# How to find CDF, if PDF of a continuous random variable X is given

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

What is the formula to compute CDF, if PDF of a continuous random variable X is given?

```
Fx(x) = {
          x         0 < x (is less than or equal to) 1
          3-x       1 < x (is less than or equal to) 2
          0         otherwise
        }
```

Comment: It is standard definitions and notation that a PDF $f_X(x)$ is positive and normalized ($\int f_X(x) dx=1$) and the CDF, $F_X(x)$ can be computed by $F_X(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x f_X(u) du$ whenever the density exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accumulate the PDF to generate the CDF.
$$  \begin{cases}
0 ,& x \leq 0  \\
0 + \frac{x^2}{2} ,& 0 < x \leq 1  \\
\frac{1}{2} + 3x - \frac{x^2}{2} - \left( 3(1) - \frac{(1)^2}{2} \right),& 1 < x \leq 2  \\
2  ,& 2 < x
\end{cases} $$

So your PDF is not normalized.  Multiply your PDF and this CDF by $\frac{1}{2}$ to normalize to one.  In each piece, the first term in the value is the last value from the previous piece of the function added to the antiderivative of the corresponding piece of the PDF with its constant of integration taken so that the antiderivative is zero at the beginning of this piece.

Comment: Thanks much Eric for the explanation.